# Routing multiple servers' traffic over another

Tags: vpn, proxy, traffic

I have multiple servers (both Windows and Linux) running in different locations.
I would like to be able to route all the traffic of those (100mbit) servers over a 1gig connection in a different location.
After having done some research myself I have stumbled onto a couple use cases but mostly for local area solutions.
Terms like VPN, proxy, NAT and iptables came up but only added to the confusion.
What would be the most appropriate solution to use?

Answer (score 0):

IPsec is what you want.

Set up IPsec tunnels between your distributed servers and a server sitting on the main 1G connection. Configure the "hub" server to be able to NAT traffic for all of the other servers, and then on the "spoke" servers, point their default gateway to the hub server's IP on the other end of the tunnel.

Comment: Okay, this gives me more specific terminology to work with and look into. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IPv6 can help here.  As mentioned you can use IPSec, or simply create a routeable address for those servers to use.